# how to send mail attachment from ubuntu 16.04 using Gmail service?

Tags: email, ubuntu-16.04, mutt, attachments, msmtp

I have been using filezilla to import/export some data from server.

How to send a file in a zip file via email in unix?

Comment: OS has nothing to do with it. GMail in a web browser works the same across all OSes and even if you use a email client software, it depends on the software used, not the OS. Many, like Thunderbird, are available for all OS families.

Comment: Could you clarify pls, how MongoDB and zip is related to sending attachment via email ??? Attachment is attachment. Look online for `msmtp` and `mutt`...

Comment: Actually i need to send a file in a zip file via email in unix, Which is solved by using mutt ==>Mutt is a small but very powerful text-based mail client for Unix operating systems

Comment: @Alex ah thanks it work you can put in answer if you want to so i can select it, ==>mutt solved my problem.

Comment: Posted full solution as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use two Ubuntu's console's packages: `msmtp` and `mutt` to send email attachment.

Install packages :

```
sudo apt-get install msmtp mutt ca-certificates
```

Configure `msmtp` to use existing email as outgoing email: (example for gmail account)

```
#!/bin/sh

echo '# Default values for all accounts.
defaults
auth           on
tls            on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile        ~/.local/msmtp.log

# Gmail
account        gmail
host           smtp.gmail.com
port           587
from           user@gmail.com
user           user@gmail.com
password       SuperSecretPassword4user@gmail.com

account default : gmail
` >~/.msmtprc
```

Prepare default `mutt` setting:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -f '~/.muttrc' ] || {
  echo '
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
set use_from=yes
set realname="Display Name"
set from=user@gmail.com
set envelope_from=yes
' > ~/.muttrc
}
```

Send email with attachment with help of `mutt`:

```
echo 'Please see attached MongoDB database...' |
  mutt -a MongoDB.zip \
       -s "Zipped MongoDB attachment ($(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))" \
       someRecipient@example.com
```

---